# How to shut down batch jobs

Tags: java, spring, jobs

Can someone describe the correct approach of shutting down batch jobs in Spring applications?

What if we want to shutdown only one type of batch jobs and be sure that we did not lose any data?

Comment: Check for this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html  section 5.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I think you can insert a logic for exit job in the business logic.
For example throwing a RuntimeException or check the specific status and make job status finished.

If there is no logic like that, killing the java process might be only way.